# Estou com problema no uso da função clearInterval

Tags: javascript

```
a_103 = setInterval( function (){ alert('oi');},3000);
id = 103;
id = "a_" + id;
clearInterval(id)
```

Estou com problema no `clearinterval`. Não consegue efetuar da forma que eu fiz, mas se eu por clearInterval(a_103); Ele vai normalmente.

alterei: clearInterval(eval(id))

Comment: poderia ter usado `clearInterval(window[id])` caso o escopo seja global

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção é não tentar criar variáveis com nomes dinâmicos, mas usar um tipo de mapa para isso.

Exemplo:

```js
var intervalos = [];
intervalos['a_103'] = setInterval(function(){ console.log('oi'); }, 3000);
...
clearInterval(intervalos['a_103']);
```

Um exemplo mais completo, criando e limpando vários *timers*:

```js
var intervalos = [];

//cria intervalos de a_1 até a_150
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    intervalos['a_' + (i+1)] = setInterval(
        function(){ console.log('oi'); }, 
        3000 + i * 100);
}

//depois
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    clearInterval(intervalos['a_' + (i+1)]);
}

//ou
clearInterval(intervalos['a_103']);
```

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/h6JRE/)

Comment: Obrigado,ja conseguir resolver.

Comment: Apesar de a minha resposta ser mais simples, considero a sua a correta, pois além de evitar o uso de ```eval()``` (que muitos não recomendam) ainda permite um número indeterminado de *intervals* sem necessidade de criação de outras variáveis "dinâmicas".

Comment: @Kazzkiq Sim, a sua resposta vai direto ao ponto. Eu somente quis indicar uma alternativa possivelmente mais "limpa", no sentido de não usar eval.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `eval()`:

```
a_103 = setInterval( function (){ alert('oi');},3000);
id = 103;
id = "a_" + id;
clearInterval(eval(id))
```

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/zZCU5/)

Comment: Obrigado,consegui resolver meu poblema.

Comment: @DieguinhoRodrigues apenas uma dica, se alguma das nossas respostas resolveu seu problema, o ideal é você marcá-la como correta para que os usuários que tenham o mesmo problema que o seu possam saber qual foi a solução que melhor te atendeu.